# How to add same queue job again if data not found in condition at the time of queue job running?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add another same queue job at the time of same job running. If job runs at the time if condition not satisfied then I need to add another queue into it for the same with 5 min delay. Is is possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets use the release function from the [InteractsWithQueue](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.html) trait:

```
class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public function handle()
    {
        // some code.

        if (! $someCondition) {
            $this->release(5);
        }         
    }
}
```

If you want to create a new job instance. Maybe this is gonna work:

```
class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public function handle()
    {
        // some code.

        if (! $someCondition) {
            dispatch($this);
            // And return if you want to terminate this job.
            return;
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kevin but $this->release(); not adding the another row into the jobs table for the same operation again.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, I hope it's gonna work.

Comment: Thanks @kevin $this->dispatch() works in my condition.